# KDE: hide / show active application windows?

Tags: python, user-interface, ubuntu, kde-plasma

I am looking at ideas to "cache" commercial/proprietary linux desktop applications running on KDE -- possibly by letting them startup normally, but hiding the GUI completely until required.

Is there a way to do this in Kde (specifically Kubuntu 16)? to simply toggle visibility of running GUI/Qt applications?

cheers,
Jorx

Comment: My thoughts so far; use QX11EmbedWidget to take a window by ID, wrap it with my custom PyQT application, and then hide()

Comment: There do exists a [LDTP](https://ldtp.freedesktop.org/user-doc/d0/d33/a00027.html) project for automation. But unfortunately you can't hide a window using the same

Comment: Hide as in minimize, or as in remove any trace of the window from the DE? Perhaps you could run the application and inmediately stop it by sending a STOP signal (for example, killall -STOP your_process), that would leave the process in memory, but wouldn't show any windows (that is, if you manage to stop the process before it creates a window).